# Extract data from ORM and group by Date

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I have a function which data like this :

```
my_workouts = Workouts.objects.groupby('my_date').filter(
    my_date__year=year, my_date__month=month)
```

I want to do the same with another model where I want to group the weight by date:

**Models.py**

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quizzes')
    scheduled_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=255, default=0)
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

What I tried:

```
data = Quiz.objects.orderby('scheduled_date').
       filter(owner_id=request.user.pk,my_date__year=year, my_date__month=month).
       annotate(c=Sum('weight')).values('c')
```

But this is not working, Please Help!

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

check your syntax

**orderby** must be **order_by**

```
data = Quiz.objects.order_by('scheduled_date').
       filter(owner_id=request.user.pk,my_date__year=year, my_date__month=month).
       annotate(c=Sum('weight')).values('c')
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

Comment: Pardon me but I wanted to group the weights by date, I mistakenly wrote orderby